# How to suppress page number?

Tags: page-numbering

I've made myself custom title-page, put it in separate `.tex` file and when I input it, it is numbered with 1. The very next page is numbered with 1 also, and page-number increases on the following pages. Main file looks like this

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{./mystyle}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{./titlepage.tex}
\input{./text.tex}
...
\end{document}
```

How do I **suppress page-number** on that **title-page**? (Why `\thispagestyle{empty}` doesn't work?)
**edit:**
Here's the title-page:

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

        % Upper part of the page
        \textsc{\large Uni}\\[0.1cm]
        \textsc{\Large Faculty}\\[2.8cm]
        \textsc{\Large Sensors}\\[0.1cm]
        {\Large Paper}\\[0.25cm] 

        % Title
        \HRule \\[0.3cm]
            { \Large \bfseries Occupancy}\\[0.3cm]
            { \huge \bfseries Tribos}\\[0.05cm]
        \HRule \\[0.05cm]

        % Author and supervisor
        \begin{center} \large
            \emph{Student:}\\
            An \textsc{Ant}
        \end{center}
        \vspace{1.8cm}
        \begin{spacing}{0}
            \tableofcontents
        \end{spacing}
        \vfill
        % Bottom of the page
        {\large \today}

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: Did you try `\pagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides As a matter of fact, it actually did turn of page-numbering, but I was unable to return it afterwards.

Comment: @everyone_with_same_problem: this fixed the problem - 1. add `\pagenumbering{gobble}` before title input 2. add `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after title input 3. add `\pagestyle{empty}` inside titlepage.tex. This could probably be generalized.

Comment: see also: [texfaq: How to get rid of page numbers](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopageno)

Answer (score 604, accepted):

You could use `\pagenumbering{gobble}` to switch off page numbering.

To switch it on afterwards, use `\pagenumbering{arabic}` for arabic numbers or `alph`, `Alph`, `roman`, or `Roman` for lowercase resp. uppercase alphabetic resp. Roman numbering.

Comment: I'm using `\pagenumbering{gobble}`, but I'm having some problems with "already used pagenumber", I'm getting the warning message `destination with the same identifier (name{page.}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again>`... and it seems to be complaining on the second page in the document. How can I fix that? I'm also using the `hyperref` package.

Comment: After switching it on again, page numbering restarts at 1.

Comment: How about keeping the page numbering without displaying it, so if the first page has gobble then the second page has the number 2? And how about resetting page numbers?

Comment: how to restart the numbering in numbers (1,2,3....) ?

Comment: You can set the pagenumbering again with `\setcounter{page}{5}`

Answer (score 74):

I had the exact same problem.  What worked for me was `\thispagestyle{empty}` after inputting the title page, not before.

Comment: This will remove both the header and footer and page numbering.

Comment: Which is what is required.

Comment: The utter simplicity of this answer is a point in its favor, even if there are contexts where the other answers are preferable.

Comment: I'm using LaTeX for a resume, which is one page long. This is the only answer that gets rid of the page number without including another blank page after.

Answer (score 26):

Maybe try to enclose your title page (or the input file) into a `\begin{titlepage}` and `\end{titlepage}`; and put `\pagenumbering{arabic}` just before your main body starts.

Comment: Thanks, that’s literally **all** that’s needed, and helped me. [Commit](https://www.teckids.org/gitweb/?p=verein.git;a=commitdiff;h=c540b2303c98687abdf321610621923bb866a7ba)

Comment: +1. This one slipped passed me ...

Answer (score 24):

```
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
```

worked for me.

Comment: And what does "worked for me" mean?  That could be all or nothing ...  Can you please explain?

Comment: It should be noted that `titlepage`s  are `empty` by default.

Comment: It should probably be noted that `\maketitle` within the `titlepage`  environment is wrong and the `\newpage` is not needed.

Answer (score 8):

Yiannis Lazarides' comment deserves its own answer: Start with

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

before the title page material and

```
\pagestyle{plain}  % or whatever page style you desire
```

after the title page material.

Comment: The original query was about suppressing the display of the page number on a specific page -- the title page, to be exact -- while not affecting the display of page numbers on other pages. Please clarify in which sense your posting addresses this objective.

Comment: @Mico Or the original query was about suppressing the display of the page number on a specific subdocument, which makes this answer relevant.  As a matter of fact, according to his own comment OP's fix was to actually combine the accepted answer with this one.  But if you feel it requires clarification, feel free to edit it, it's community wiki. ;)

Comment: I suppose that it's not entirely wrong to call the titlepage of a document a "sub-document". :-) (That's not the term the OP used, though...) I've taken you up on the offer to apply some edits to your answer.

Comment: Since OP specified the titlepage had its own `.tex` file, I guess it's technically correct at least server-side…