# \pagestyle{empty} doesn't work on first page of new chapter

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, page-numbering

I have a problem with page numbering in LaTeX. I don't want any page number in my document so I used `\pagestyle{empty}` but every time when I start a new chapter I get a page number on the bottom center of the page with the chapter's title. What should I do to remove those page numbers?

My document class looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
```

Comment: See also [How to suppress the page number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7355/how-to-suppress-page-number).

Comment: @Stephen: American spelling doesn't need to be corrected `;)`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: @doncherry: Ups! Ok, when editing I just changed everything in the way I would write it (BE) and did not think about it possibly being right in AE. If it had only been `center` vs. `centre` I would *not* have edited it, of course. But thanks for pointing out, I'll regard it next time.

Comment: another question on same topic: [how to remove page numbers from first page of chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103567/579)

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{book}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\chapter{abc}
blub
\newpage
blub
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

at the start of the document and

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

at the start of each new chapter/section/... should suppress page numbering, other than for `part`.

To remove all page numbering it may be simpler to

```
\usepackage{nopageno}
```

as this makes `\pagestyle{plain}` have the same effect as `\pagestyle{empty}` thus removing all the page numbering without having to specify it for every section.

Answer (score 5):

The "cleanest" solution is to say

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
```

in the document's preamble. On the other hand, I would normally advise against having no page numbers, except for very specific applications.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, this should work:

```
\chapter{blabla}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

(I can't test it on this pc, sorry.)

However I'm sure there are cleaner solutions. One is to use [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/), which allows you to (relatively) easily customize the style first page of a chapter.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to change the used pagestyle like this:

```
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}

\renewpagestyle{plain}{
(0pt,0pt)
{}
{}
{}
(0pt,0pt)
}{
(0pt,0pt)
{} 
{} 
{}
(0pt,0pt)
}
```

take a look at this document: ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguide.pdf

Comment: though no one voted for this answer but I think redefine the plain page style is the best way to go. Having `thispagestyle` manually on the start of every chapter is not practical. Modify internal macros like `\ps@plain` should not be advocated unless it is absolutely necessary. `\pagenumbering{gobble}` has the side effect of reseting page numbers.