# how to remove page numbers from first page of chapters

Tags: header-footer, chapters, page-numbering

My report requires page numbers to start from 1st chapter 1st page.
So I use

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

just before I do

```
\include{tex_files/chapter1)Introduction}
```

Now I want the page counting to start from 1st page, but I dont want the page numbers to appear on the first page of each chapter.

How to do this?

**Answer :**
Quick (and dirty?) solution: `\thispagestyle{empty}` just after `\chapter{...}`.

Comment: Quick (and dirty?) solution: `\thispagestyle{empty}` just after `\chapter{...}`.

Answer (score 14):

In the report class, it's the `\chapter` command that selects the page style for the first chapter page:

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

Thus a solution is to change `plain` into `empty`, by adding the following to the document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{empty}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
```

If you don't plan to use the `plain` pagestyle, then a simpler

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
```

would suffice.

A similar patch should probably be made also to `\part`; you can get both with this alternative code that doesn't require looking at `report.cls` in order to find the definitions:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{}{}
\patchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}
```

Comment: Hi, egreg, I use ```\chapter*``` for Abstract and other front matter. This solution removes the page number from their first page as well. I tried ```\renewcommand\chapter*``` with ```\thispagestyle{plain}``` but that doesn't compile.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania I find no reason for omitting the page number in some chapters and not in others. Actually I find no reason for omitting the page number anywhere.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania You might patch `\@schapter`  with `\preto\@schapter{\thispagestyle{plain}}`

Comment: My bad. I meant hide page numbers and not remove them. That is my university's requirement.

Answer (score 5):

The best answer to this question depends on your document class and packages you want to load. One possibility would be [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}%The first page in each chapter won't have any heading or footer, especially no page number
\title{foobar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}%All pages from now on won't have any heading or footer, especially no page number [will be changed later on]
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
The following text uses Lorem Ipsum.
\chapter{eins}
\pagestyle{plain}%All pages, except first pages of each chapters, from now on will have the page number in the footer
\pagenumbering{arabic}%Sets page numbers to be Western Numerals and resets the page count to start at 1
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{uno}
\lipsum[11-20]
\section{due}
\lipsum[21-30]
\chapter{zwei}
\lipsum[31-40]
\section{wahid}
\lipsum[41-50]
\section{itneen}
\lipsum[51-60]
\chapter{drei}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using the `report` or `book` document class, or a class that's based on/derived from one of these classes, you could achieve your goal by modifying the `plain` page style. This works because in the `report` and `book` document classes, the `plain` page style is used only for the initial pages of *chapters* and chapter-like entities such as the *Index*.

The following MWE redefines the `\ps@plain` macro, which sets up the `plain` page style. Just copy and paste the lines beginning with `\makeatletter` and ending with `\makeatother` to your document's preamble, and you should be all set.

```
\documentclass{report} % or "book"
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\@oddhead\@empty
     \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil}
     \let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{report} % or "book"
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP wanted _each_ chapter page to not have page numbers.

Comment: This globally changes `\ps@plain` to `\ps@empty`, so doing the `\let` once would be the same. Why `\noexpand`?

Comment: @egreg: why not ;-)   I forgot about the g in `\g@addto@macro`