# No page number on the first page of an Index (not ToC)

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, indexing, fancyhdr

The publishing house I am going to publish a book with demands no page number on the first page of each chapter. I used `\thispagestyle{empty}` in most cases and had to use `\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{empty}}` for no number on the first page of the bibliography. But I could not find a solution for no page number on the first page of the Indexes. Is there anything like `\bibsetup` which works for the Indexes? You will see below that I tried already with `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}`, but it did not work.

Here is an excerpt of my file:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, blindtext}
\begin{document}
%then the text

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\printbibliography
%this command works nicely

\thispagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103589/5001 for an answer that suppresses the page number automatically on the first page of the *Index* as well as the first page of every *chapter*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you're using `fancyhdr`, you may simply use `\fancypagestyle` to redefine the `plain` pagestyle (which is used for chapter-starting pages) so that it resembles the `empty` style. This works for "normal" chapters, for a bibligraphy created with `biblatex`, and for the index.

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Some text \autocite{A01}\index{Alpha}.

\printbibliography

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Good morning, the cause of the problem, so to speak, is the definition of the `theindex` environment from the class file, e.g. `article.cls`, `book.cls` etc., which is used in the `ind` file. We include this file by calling the `\printindex` command. The problem is that it contains `\thispagestyle{empty}` and it overwrites our external efforts.

My approach is to overwrite/wrap it before it gets chance to overwrite us. Please use one line at a time from lines 2-4 to get some common situations.

```
\let\originalstyle=\thispagestyle            % Store the command for later reuse.
%\def\thispagestyle#1{\fancyfoot[C]{}}       % This clears footer in the center if fancyhdr is in use.
%\def\thispagestyle#1{\originalstyle{empty}} % Use this to get blank header+footer, TeXnically it is only \thispagestyle{empty}.
\def\thispagestyle#1{}                       % This line completely ignores the content of the \thispagestyle command.
\printindex                                  % Typeset the actual Index.
\let\thispagestyle=\originalstyle            % Let's get back to the original version of the \thispagestyle, if needed later in the document.
```