# How to remove page number at the first page and the blank page of each chapter?

Tags: page-numbering, blank-page

I am at present typing a manuscript in WinEdt 8.0 and got stuck in the following page set up problem. Please help me out. Allow me to state the situation in short-details.

The publisher demanded that the print out will be done in `letterpaper` with `11pt` font size. Now I am habituated in page set up with `a4paper` always. Hence I was little confused about but later I changed the option `a4paper` in the option of `\documentclass`.

Below I have provided the sample. Please have a look and edit if you wish.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{document}      
%=========    
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.3in}  
\setlength{\headsep}{0.1in}     
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}  
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.3in} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{.2in}       
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}     
%========    
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}                  
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%============
\begin{document}
\chapter{Apple}
Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. 

\chapter{Kolkata}
Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. 

    \chapter{Chennai}
text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. 

    \chapter{Mumbai}
Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. Text. text. 

    \end{document}
```

Now let me tell you my haphazard that I am facing.

(1) I request you to kindly copy and past the above sample in your own WinEdt and compile/run there. Before that, increase the words "text" so many so that in the output each chapter will be  at least 4-5 pages long. Its necessary cause then only I will be able to make my situation precise. My problem is: each chapter is having page number at the bottom, in fact at the extreme bottom but the remaining page numbers are in the above, making the page set up proper. Is it possible, that each chapter is starting with no the page number? What command should I use ?

(2)Now the next problem. After the compilation is done, I am getting some blank pages at the end of most chapters with the header name as the chapter name. How to remove that ?

Mean to say, e.g. chapter `2` is ending with one blank page at the end and it is having the header `Chapter 2:Bla bla` . How shall I remove that blank page ?

Please help me. And also edit the portion in this post if you desire. I have tried my best sincerely to make it clear what situation I am having.

Thanking you

Comment: I think problem one I have managed. I found here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103567/how-to-remove-page-numbers-from-first-page-of-chapters the solution how to remove the page number from first page of each chapter. Am I right ?

Comment: The link should provide at least some ideas. Since you're using `geometry`, there's no need to manually set the `topmargin` etc. before. And if there's too less content for pages, an empty page will be used to give the possibility to start on an odd page again (that's the default for chapters, unless `openany` is used) -- And which is the class `document`? I think it's a typo and it should read `book` or `report`, most likely

Comment: For this and future problems, I suggest you to use the `lipsum` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) when you need to type a lot of text just to fill up pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `book` class the standard is that chapters start on the right side, i.e. the odd-numbered page (*recto page*). This will lead to empty even-numbered pages (*verso page*) occur of course, if there's not enough typesetting content to fill the last page before a new chapter starts.

The `openany` documentclass option to `book` allows chapters to start on verso pages. (`report` uses `openany` by default)

By default `chapters` use a numbered start page (the page number is most times at the bottom then), i.e. the pagestyle is `plain`. If this is not wanted, use `\thispagestyle{empty}` and the patch command `\xpatchcmd` which replaces the page style definition.

Removing the page number however omits the information which page it is, of course -- this can be quite confusing.

In addition:

- Use the various options of `geometry` package instead of manipulating the internal layout settings directly. Please change the settings to the needs.
- Use the `blindtext` package to generate portions of dummy text just to show some effect and filling up the pages.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany,letterpaper]{book}      
%=========    
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-.3in}  
%\setlength{\headsep}{0.1in}     
%\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}  
%\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.3in} 
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.3in}
%\setlength{\topskip}{.2in}       
%\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}     
%========    
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[headsep=0.1in,lmargin=0.8in,rmargin=0.8in,letterpaper]{geometry}                  
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Removing plain style and replace it with empty style for the chapter start page
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}



\usepackage{blindtext}
%============
\begin{document}
\chapter{Apple}
\blindtext[12]
\chapter{Kolkata}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Chennai}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Mumbai}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]