# How to remove new page numbering in \listoffigures?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I have a List of figures section in my tex document and I'm using \listoffigures

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage    
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

[image]

This is what I want but then, there's one more image and it goes onto the next page and shows something like this

[image]

There's a page number at the bottom of the page and the formatting seems to have changed with the top. How can I avoid this?

Comment: It looks like you are using `fancyhdr` to make a fancy header. By default there is no header for pages which are the start of chapters. The list of figures is a new chapter. You can get rid of this in your front matter by doing a `\pagestyle{empty}` and then when you want to go back to the fancy stuff to `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Answer (score 1):

Do something along the lines of

```latex
\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

For a full example (using [a solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103610/106804) from [how to remove page numbers from first page of chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103567/how-to-remove-page-numbers-from-first-page-of-chapters) to ensure no page nujmbering on chapters or part pages) I would use:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,20pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103610/106804
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{}{}
\patchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\lipsum[1]
\end{titlepage}
\pagestyle{empty}   
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Some figures}
\section{Some section}
\begin{figure}[htb]Something\caption{\lipsum[1]}\end{figure} 
\begin{figure}[htb]Something\caption{\lipsum[1]}\end{figure} 
\begin{figure}[htb]Something\caption{\lipsum[1]}\end{figure} 
\begin{figure}[htb]Something\caption{\lipsum[1]}\end{figure} 
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This gives no headers or footers for the list of figures, but returns to normal style for the main body (except new chapter or part pages).