# Begin page counting from a given page

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing a thesis and I wanna know how could I make to begin counting pages from a given page that I choose instead from the very first one.

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? I would use `\newcommand{\gobble}[1]{}\pagenumbering{gobble}` and then when you want to start the page numbering, issue `\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}`. The `\clearpage` may not be necessary.

Comment: See [How to suppress page number?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7355/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thepage{}
...
... some pages
...
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
...
... some more pages with a pagenumber
```