# A pdf output with exact output dimensions

Tags: xetex, output

I want to create a `.jpg` picture from `.pdf` with exactly these `real` dimensions to include this `.jpg` into my Mobile Phone Samsung Flip Z3 as specified [here](https://smartmania.cz/srovnani-parametru-samsung-galaxy-z-flip-vs-z-flip-3/) into my Android Studio Application. Can someone kindly give me an MWE saying `hello world` for the LaTeX
source code which would have the working effective area with these exact dimensions?

Comment: Standalaone wnd minipage can specify a PDF with a given width and height.  You might also look at a graphics editor to specify images by pixels size .  I use GIMP to create wallpaper with at 16x9 aspect ratio.

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly, but if you simply want to convert/resize a pdf => jpg, when and where does LaTeX come into play?

Comment: @Ingmar I'll try to explain. I want to create pdf with a specific size. The convertion then will be easy, I presume the size will be preserved by the online convertor. For that pdf I want it to have the precise size so that I do not need another resizing.

Comment: There are pdfTeX primitives `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight`. If you say (for example) `\pdfpagewidth=14.5cm` then the width of a virtual paper in the PDF is exactly 14.5cm. What do you need more?

Comment: That website is in Czech or something. I can't read it. But you can specify the output "paper" size with `\usepackage[papersize={640pt,480pt}]{geometry}` or whatever dimensions. You'll probably want to set the margin too. `\usepackage[papersize={640pt,480pt},margin=0pt]{geometry}`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494227/output-images-of-math-with-169-aspect-ratio-using-standalone-package/494230?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C29.0974#494230