# Removing the space the page number takes up

Tags: spacing, margins, page-numbering

For example, in a default document...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

...the space between the text and the bottom of the page
is significantly larger
than the space between the text and the top of the page.
(on the first page in this example).

This makes sense when the page number is there,
but removing the page number does not extend the text further down the page,
and the space is the same size
as it would be if the page number were there.

[Other ways of removing the page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7355/how-to-suppress-page-number),
like this...

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

...or this...

```
\usepackage{nopageno}
```

...have the same result.

I know I can specify custom margins with `geometry`
that ignore the page number,
but is there a way to just remove the space
that the page number used to take up,
so that the bottom is the same size as the top margin?

Comment: If you want to change the page layout you will have to use e.g. geometry. The size of the text box doesn't change if you remove text from the footer box.

Comment: If you add \usepackage{showframe} you will see that the text area doesn't change.

Comment: @john-kormylo With `showframe` added to the above example,
there is a line below the main section where the page number would be.
What is the line for?  How do I stretch the main text down to the line?

Comment: The line shows the location of the footer (unlike the header, the footer is only described by \footsep).  `\advance \textheight by \footsep \setlength{\footsep}{0pt}`  Except for exam class, which puts the footer below the line instead of above.