# Truly center block of text and equations on a flashcard

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, margins

So I am trying to create a series of small flashcards A6 size as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}%
\usepackage[a6paper, landscape, left=10mm, right=10mm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry

% ============================================================
% v OWN COMMANDS AND PACKAGES BELOW HERE v
% ============================================================

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mengder}{HTML}{093145}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7355/how-to-suppress-page-number
\pagenumbering{gobble} % 

\begin{document}

\Huge

%==============================================================================%
%                                Mengder                                %
%==============================================================================%

\pagecolor{mengder}
\color{white}

% \setfpvar{angle.p8}{10+5*\randomint{3}{11}}
%\setfpvar{angle.p8}{40 + 5*\randomint{0}{4}} % random.randrange(40,60,5)
\include{Q1-mengder-utsagn}
\include{Q2-mengder-SnittOgUnion}
\include{Q3-mengder-listeform}

\nopagecolor

\end{document}
```

Where my flashcards are defined as follows

**Q1-mengder-utsagn.tex**

```
La $\{3, 5, 7\}$ og $B = \{3, 7\}$ \bigskip

Hvilke utsagn er sanne? \bigskip

\begin{center}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[label={$\square$}]
            \item $3 \in B$
            \item $0 \in A$
            \item $A \subset B$
            \item $5, 7 \in A$
            \item $B \subset A$
            \item $10 \not \in A$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{center}
```

**Q2-mengder-SnittOgUnion.tex**

```
La $R = \{2,5,7,11\}$ \\ \phantom{S}\! og $S = \{5,7,11,15\}$

\bigskip

Finn\bigskip

\begin{center}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[label={$\square$}]
            \item $R \cap S$
            \item $R \cup S$
            \item $R \setminus S$
            \item $S \setminus R$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{center}
```

**Q3-mengder-listeform.tex**

```
Gitt $M=\{6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$. \\ 

\bigskip 

Finn 

\bigskip

\begin{center}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \mbox{$A = \{ x \in M \mid x \neq 7, x \neq 10\}$}
        \item $A = \{ x + 7 \mid x \in M\}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{center}
```

The output now looks like

[image]

Where I would expect a centered output, to look more like

[image]

E.G the widest part of the textblock is equally far away from the margins.
Similar is true for the top and bottom part of the textblock. Is there a non-manual way to acheive this? (I need around a hundred of these cards).

I also have tried to following the advice given here, [center horizontally and vertically a block of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70714/center-horizontally-and-vertically-a-block-of-text). Without much success. Eg rewriting

**Q1-mengder-utsagn.tex**

as

```
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{list}{}{%
  \leftmargin=0pt
  \rightmargin=0pt
  \listparindent=\parindent
  \itemindent=\parindent
  \itemsep=0pt
  \parsep=0pt}
\item\relax

La $\{3, 5, 7\}$ og $B = \{3, 7\}$ \bigskip

Hvilke utsagn er sanne? \bigskip

\begin{center}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[label={$\square$}]
            \item $3 \in B$
            \item $0 \in A$
            \item $A \subset B$
            \item $5, 7 \in A$
            \item $B \subset A$
            \item $10 \not \in A$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{center}

\end{list}
\vfill % equivalent to \vspace{\fill}
```

gives

[image]

which clearly is not centered either. What am I doing wrong?
I have tried adding minipages and centerings without much success.

Comment: I would use a tabular instead of enumerate.  Enumerate uses the whole column whether it needs it or not.  Tabular usually shrinks to fit the largest entry in each column (just don't use p{] columns).

Comment: Good suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

(1)  Center the text area in the page setting the margins with `geometry`

(2) Inside the flashcards, center the content vertically.

This solution defines the environment `CenterCard` with three parameters:

1. Contents of the top of the flashcard;
2. Elements to be displayed at the bottom, up to three elements per
   line. Each line has the  form  `item1 & item2 \\` or just  `item1 \\`;
3. Symbols to insert before each elements. A counter is provided to
   simulate the environment `enumerate`.

`CenterCard` uses the environment `varwidth`, similar to `minipage` but with a resulting width of the natural width of its contents; and a `tabular` environment to present the elements in columns.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}%
\usepackage[a6paper,
landscape, 
left=10mm,
right=10mm,
marginparsep=0pt, 
marginparwidth=0pt,
vmargin=9mm, % save space  for printing
ignoreheadfoot,
]{geometry}% changed <<<<
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt} % added  <<<<

% ============================================================
% v OWN COMMANDS AND PACKAGES BELOW HERE v
% ============================================================
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,array}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{enumitem} % not used
%\usepackage{multicol}  % not used

\usepackage{varwidth}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mengder}{HTML}{093145}

\usepackage{showframe} % show the margins <<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7355/how-to-suppress-page-number
\pagenumbering{gobble} % 

\newcounter{CellNumber}% to add numbers to the cells
\newenvironment{CenterCard}[3]{%
\parindent0pt
\setcounter{CellNumber}{0}
\pagecolor{mengder}
\color{white}\Huge
\vspace*{\fill}\nointerlineskip
\begin{center}\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth} #1\end{varwidth}\end{center}\bigskip%
\begin{center}
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{30pt}% separation of the columns <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}% extra row separation <<<
        \begin{tabular}{*{3}{>{#3}l}}
            #2}
        {%
        \end{tabular}\setcounter{CellNumber}{0}
    \end{varwidth}
\end{center}
\vfill \clearpage}  

\begin{document}
    

%%      
%%      %==============================================================================%
%%      %                                Mengder                                %
%%      %==============================================================================%

%%      
\begin{CenterCard}
    {La $\{3, 5, 7\}$ og $B = \{3, 7\}$ \bigskip
    
    Hvilke utsagn er sanne? \bigskip}
    {%
    $3 \in B$ &$5, 7 \in A$ \\
    $0 \in A$ & $A \subset B$ \\    
    $B \subset A$ & $10 \not \in A$}        
    {$\square$\enspace}
\end{CenterCard}


\begin{CenterCard}
    {La $R = \{2,5,7,11\}$ \\  og $S = \{5,7,11,15\}$   
    \bigskip
    
    Finn\bigskip}
    {%
    $R \cap S$ & $R \setminus S$ \\
    $R \cup S$  & $S \setminus R$
    }       
    {$\square$\enspace}
\end{CenterCard}

\begin{CenterCard}
    {Gitt $M=\{6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$. \\  
    \bigskip 
    
    Finn    
    \bigskip}
    {%
    \mbox{$A = \{ x \in M \mid x \neq 7, x \neq 10\}$}  \\  
     $A = \{ x + 7 \mid x \in M\}$
    }
    {\stepcounter{CellNumber}\theCellNumber)\enspace}
\end{CenterCard}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar This is the only requirement left? I thought that the problem was centering.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I will update the answer. Any solution depends on the templates you have for the cards. So far there are two different. Do you have more?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Please try the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try with images later.